# Resizing the div with respect to visibilty and non-visibilty of other div (in javascript only)

Tags: javascript

Need to resize the 'article' div when 'sidebar' div is visible, things go fine for first two clicks made on the 'Button'. But when the 'Button' is clicked third time the only white-space appears in place of sidebar. The expected behavior is to move 'article' div when sidebar appears and when sidebar doesn't appear it can occupy all the area.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  var y = document.getElementById("article");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
     y.style.left = "160px";
     console.log('if-execution...margin 160');
   } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
     y.style.marginLeft = "0px";
     console.log('else-exection...margin 0');
   }
  }
```

```css
  #sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 51px;
 left: 0; 
 background-color: #111;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 padding: 10px 0px;
}

 #article {
    margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMenu()">Button</button>

<div id="sidebar">
  <a href="#about">About1</a>
  <a href="#services">Services1</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients1</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact1</a>
</div>

<div id="article">
 <h3>Article</h3>
   <p>This is is main content area.</p>
   <span style='font-size:100px;'>&#9971;</span>
   <p>This is is main content area.</p>
   <p>This is is main content area.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.left = "160px";
    console.log('if-execution...margin 160');
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.left = "0"; // added this line
    y.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    console.log('else-exection...margin 0');
}
```